# What are the deprecation policies for legacy group?

Tags: kubernetes

I have been going through the Kubernetes documentation and found that there are several API groups:

Question 1) Is core API also a API group or apps,batch etc come under API groups?
Question 2) I have seen that when a new feature is released it is of alpha version, as it becomes more stable eventually becomes apis/v1(stable version) which can only be deprecated during major releases of kubernetes. But nothing about the core APIs was said in the documentation. Are they by default considered Stable? and the same rules as the named group API applies to them? Can someone help me understand the deprecation of core API and let me know if any core API so far was deprecated.

I have gone through  the kubernetes documentation regarding API groups https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups

and about API versioning https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-versioning

And the API versioning seems to be for named groups only.. Am I wrongly understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Core" is the API group that contains Namespaces, Pods, ConfigMaps, and a set of other common things.  It also tends to be things that existed earlier in Kubernetes's lifetime; Deployments and Jobs are widespread but are in different API groups (`apps` and `batch` respectively).

In many contexts, such as the Go [GroupVersionKind](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.27.1/pkg/runtime/schema#GroupVersionKind) structure or [Role objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example) in the role-based access control (RBAC) system, an empty string refers to the core API group.

The core API group is a normal API group.  As your [first link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups) notes, if you're directly using the Kubernetes REST API, its URLs are constructed a little differently, but the various Kubernetes SDKs usually handle this difference for you.  It acts like a normal API group in basically all other ways.

Like other API groups, the core API group has a version.  Its current version is `v1`, which is a stable version.

Kubernetes has deprecated *beta* versions of API groups; removing `apps/v1beta1` and `batch/v1beta1` has been mildly disruptive in environments I've worked on.  I'm not familiar with very early Kubernetes history but in ~7 years of working with Kubernetes I don't recall ever running across a `v1beta1` or other similar pre-release version of the core API group.

Comment: Thank you for answering, so same deprecation policies apply to the core group too? that since the version is of stable, it wont be deprecated in minor releases?

Comment: That is definitely my understanding.